React: how to load and render external html file that has a script?
In my project, I have a description page which written in html. I use javascript inside that file for show neccessary content. But when I use dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: sample.html} to render the html file, javascript part is not working.
So how can I render a html file that has javascript inside that html?

Why are you using SetInnerHTML?  Is this a full response, or is this an AJAX request?

dangerouslySetInnerHTML uses innerHTML, which doesn't execute scripts. You could use createContextualFragment, or parse out the scripts manually from the string. I haven't tested it, but this package looks like it would work.

When you use dangerouslySetInnerHTML in React to render HTML content, it simply sets the inner HTML of a component. However, it doesn't execute JavaScript within that HTML content. If you need to render HTML content that includes JavaScript code and have that JavaScript executed, you have a couple of options:

Use innerHTML directly: Instead of using dangerouslySetInnerHTML, you can directly set the innerHTML property of a DOM element. This will execute any JavaScript code present in the HTML content. However, be cautious as this approach can pose security risks if the HTML content is user-generated or not trusted.

Separate JavaScript from HTML: If possible, refactor your code to separate the JavaScript logic from the HTML content. You can include the JavaScript logic in your React component or in a separate JavaScript file and then manipulate the DOM or React components accordingly.


Here's an example of how you can use innerHTML directly:
function MyComponent({ htmlContent }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    container.innerHTML = htmlContent;
  }, [htmlContent]);

  return <div id="container"></div>;
}

And then use MyComponent like this:
<MyComponent htmlContent={sample.html} />

Remember to consider security implications and only use this approach if you trust the source of the HTML content.
